# Run command from non-elevated cmd as admin

Tags: windows, command-prompt, startup, repair, bsod

We are having a large amount of devices with startup issues that could be resolved via startup repair. The issue is startup repair fails due to bitlocker (thanks microsoft). From windows troubleshooting, you can open a cmd window that is non-elevated. I cannot enter in the commands needed due to non admin elevation. Is there a way I can do a "Runas" where I can enter admin username and pw to elevate the window so I can execute the appropriate commands?

non-elevated window comes back with error due non-admin.